# how to get single record from SQS trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We are getting all the records sqs event trigger at once how to get or limit the trigger to get only  one at a time?

```
public class sqslambda implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void> {
  @Override
  public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
    try {
      for (SQSEvent.SQSMessage message : event.getRecords()) {

       String input = message.getBody();

      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error("Exception handling batch seed request.", ex);
      throw ex;
    }
    return null;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an **event source mapping** to tell Lambda to send items from an Amazon SQS queue to an AWS Lambda function.

As part of this configuration, you can define the **batch size**, which specifies "the largest number of records that will be read from your queue at once".

Therefore, you should go to your Lambda function, click on the **SQS trigger** and set the Batch Size to one.

See also: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

Comment: There the batch size was only set to one, How to run lambda function in multiple threads.

Comment: If you mean "How can I run multiple Lambda functions simultaneously", then this is handled automatically by AWS Lambda. You can set the **Reserve Concurrency** to limit the number of concurrent executions of the function. See: [Managing Concurrency - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html)